# execute block of code independently in the function in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got stuck in unique scenario.
I have a function "hello()" that **should** executes in every 10 seconds.
Now, I have a requirement that within the same function a piece of code should run after **every** 60 seconds independent of the 10 sec execution.
What would be the best way to achieve it. Thanks.

Sample code:

```
import time
def hello():
    while True:
        print "Hello World"
        time.sleep(10)
        #Do something after every 60 seconds
        #Do something after every 86400 seconds
```

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

As I realized, you have 3 independent processes. One approach is defining three independent threads and make each run every X seconds.
By the way, You should use the newer version of Python

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process
import time

def f(seconds):
  while True:
    print("%s runs every %d seconnds" % (current_process().name, seconds) )
    time.sleep(n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p = Pool(3)
  print([w.name for w in p._pool])
  p.map(f, [10, 60, 10])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing by threads? You can make 3 threads with independent timers

Comment: How to use thread in my case, please suggest. M still learning python. thanks!